# Is Ruby on Rails or Spring the first successful MVC web architecture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

From the historic view, is Ruby on Rails or Spring the first MVC dev platform?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring predates RoR by several years, in terms of popularity / success, I think it's fair to say that RoR has been more successful than Spring.

Within the Java community Spring was extremely successful, but it should be noted that before RoR there was barely any Ruby community at all, and it's fairly obvious that RoR is responsible for the huge Ruby community that we have today.

Spring is definitely the first MVC framework to become "famous", but RoR revolutionised the Ruby community and is a far more popular framework now.

Comment: Well, it's a bit apples and oranges really .... but the use of Ruby (dynamic vs static types) and  more automation, but RoR is a more complete development environment, due to the inclusion of the Console and Server wrapper. Someone mentioned full-stack... that nails it.

Comment: it's a stretch to say RoR is more popular than Spring. Spring is a framework for Java applications, and under this umbrella framework is their MVC framework. Just going by the numbers.... more people are and have worked with Spring MVC than RoR (which shouldn't be surprising considering how hugely popular Java is compared to Ruby) - http://trends.builtwith.com/framework

Comment: "Just going by the numbers" - I suppose you can understand that I wasn't.  Java / spring is something you fall into, Ruby (at least at the time of writing 5 years ago.) was much harder to find work using. Yet Rails still exhibited enormous growth, and pretty much turned server development on its head.  If we reworded 'popular' with something more specific, describing the type of popularity, maybe that would help.  Personally I don't take much stock in 'just numbers'.  I suppose you have to have some perspective to see beyond them though.

Answer (score 8):

No, neither one was. MVC predates web development altogether, it originated with fat client GUI applications. With respect to web apps, people were writing MVC-style webapps (called Model-2 back in the day) with JSPs and servlets back before web frameworks became popular.

Spring and RoR are not all that comparable. Spring is a toolkit, RoR is a full-stack solution. RoR is similar to Roo or Grails (both of which use Spring as a big part of their implementation).

Comment: I think Turbine (http://turbine.apache.org/) was the first successful MVC web framework, at least in Java space.

Comment: @Neeme Praks: yes, Turbine would be my first guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can see from this [article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364527/Introduction-to-the-Spring-Framework) that Spring MVC existed before Ruby on Rails was first released (July 2004).

Comment: since spring predated RoR several years, why Ruby can become popular suddently?